# Spawn multiple processes with a single command

Tags: bash, command-line, process, parallelism

Is there a way to create say 10 instances of a process (for example yes) with a single command?

```
$instantiate 10 yes
```

Answer (score 5):

Would something like the following be OK? This assumes bash (for brace expansion) and GNU parallel.

```
parallel -N0 -j0 -u yes ::: {1..10}
```

The `-j0` setting is there to make sure as many processes as parameters get started, and `-u` (ungroup) is there so that the output of each process is printed as soon as it is available (this matters in the case of `yes`, since its output is infinite). `-N0` prevents arguments from being inserted into the command line.

Comment: The `\; : {}` can be avoided by using `-N0`. If you want to run as many in parallel as possible `-j0` is a better choise: It will automatically adjust if it cannot spawn new processes.

Comment: Good point, I integrated your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@dhag certainly has a one-line answer, but the syntax makes my eyes hurt. :)

Since you asked for a single command, and since the shell considers for-do-done a single (compound) command, I feel justified with this much more readable version:

```
for i in {1..10}; do yes &; done
```

Note that some shells automatically `nice(2)` background jobs, so if that's an issue then this isn't the best solution.

Comment: GNU parallel does have a strange syntax, but once you go through its tutorial for one hour, you'll thank yourself for the rest of your life for the powers it will arm you with :)

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Comment: Since you provided no other information (shell version, OS version, etc), my only response is, "You've got a typo."